# I need to parse strings out of a TStringStream using a substring delimiter in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, stream, substring, delphi-xe, stringstream

Using Delphi XE,
I need to parse a TStringStream into strings delimited by a String.
The delimiter-string in one case would be [eol].
The stream is loaded from a webserver using indy IdHttp.

I then need to parse the strings out of the Stream, and they are separated by the string "[eol]".
As an example the StringStream could contain:

"12345[eol]this is] something[eol]and [this is nothing[eol]etc[etcetc[[eol]"

should parse into:

"12345"

"this is] something"

"and [this is nothing"

"etc[etcetc["

Most delimiter techniques I know use only single character delimiters, and then I also need to iterate through the entire Stream until its end.
I'm at a loss,

Regards
Adrian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are already using Indy, you can use its `SplitColumnsNoTrim()` function to split a `String` into a `TStrings` using a delimiter String that can contain multiple characters in it.  As it name suggests, `SplitColumnsNoTrim()` does not apply any trimming between the separated substrings.  If you want trimming, use `SplitColumns()` instead.

```
var
  Strm: TStringStream;
  Strings: TStringList;
begin
  Strings := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Strm := TStringStream.Create;
    try
      IdHTTP.Get('http://...', Strm);
      SplitColumnsNoTrim(Strm.DataString, Strings, '[eol]'); 
    finally
      Strm.Free;
    end;
    // use Strings as needed ...
  finally
    Strings.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I would not advise using a `TStringStream` for this kind of parsing, though.  `TStringStream` in D2009+ requires you to specify a `TEncoding` in its constructor (or let it default to the OS default Ansi encoding), which you cannot do if you have `TIdHTTP` download directly into the `TStringStream`. You won't know the charset of the data ahead of time, unless the data is always ASCII.  `TIdHTTP` has logic to decode the downloaded data into a `String` using the data's actual charset, so you should utilize that functionality instead, eg:

```
var
  Strings: TStringList;
begin
  Strings := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SplitColumnsNoTrim(IdHTTP.Get('http://...'), Strings, '[eol]'); 
    // use Strings as needed ...
  finally
    Strings.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thx Remy, that did the trick. I will take your advice with the TStringStream too.